# Can iptables be used to prevent internal connection?

Tags: iptables

I can set iptables rules to prevent external connection. But can we use iptables to prevent internal connection? For example, I have set iptables to prevent port 5555 port on my machine, but my local APP can still connect with 5555 when running on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can block it using iptables.

```
iptables -A INPUT -d 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 5555 -j DROP
```

With this command you'll not be able to connect from your own host to your own service. Then you can remove the rule using the opposite to -A `append` which is -D `delete`:

```
iptables -D INPUT -d 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 5555 -j DROP
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Depends upon how you are blocking the port 5555, if you have a specific INPUT rule with interface and source and/or destination addresses it would match only those. In your case, you could modify your rule to just match tcp destination port 5555 and it will block all packets to tcp destination port 5555. for eg:

`iptables -t filter -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 5555 -j DROP`

If you just want to block your internal apps and not touch your existing iptables rule then use the incoming interface as `lo` for eg:

`iptables -t filter -I INPUT -i lo -p tcp --dport 5555 -j DROP`

Note: If you are using destination ip then use the entire loopback address range rather than just 127.0.0.1 for eg:

`iptables -t filter -I INPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 -p tcp --dport 5555 -j DROP`

Before you do any changes you can instead of `-j DROP` action use `-j LOG` action to log and confirm the tcp connections this rule will match. You could also skip the action part without specifying the `-j` option and check how many packets would match your rule with `iptables -t filter -L -n -v` without causing any harm.